# Bootstrap dropdown menu jQuery conflicts with other libraries?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have installed some jQuery components on [my website](http://www.helpmyedu.com/asdtest-2/), a Bootstrap dropdown menu, a banner slider and a content slider.

Currently the dropdown menu doesn't work while the banner slider & content slider works fine.
I have tried to disable the jQuery link from the content slider (which made the dropdown menu back to work), so I know they're conflicting.

The dropdown menu jQuery is located here:

```
<script src="http://www.helpmyedu.com/wp-content/themes/parallelus-moxie/assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
```

And the content slider jQuery is located here:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

How can I combine them two?

Thanks

=======UPDATE====================================================

I for some reason deleted the line:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And everything worked......

Thanks guys!

Comment: Which dropdown are you referring too they all seem to work?

Comment: The very top ones, where it says "Events" & "iaeMembership"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you don't need to call same scripts.

```
<script src="http://www.helpmyedu.com/wp-content/themes/parallelus-moxie/assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
/*! jQuery v1.10.2 | (c) 2005, 2013 jQuery Foundation, Inc. | jquery.org/license
//@ sourceMappingURL=jquery-1.10.2.min.map
*/

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
/*! jQuery v1.10.2 | (c) 2005, 2013 jQuery Foundation, Inc. | jquery.org/license
//@ sourceMappingURL=jquery.min.map
*/
```

They are of different sources but both jQuery v1.10.2. Just use one and put that over the other javascript you are using.

**NOTE :** My answer is based on:

> Currently the dropdown menu doesn't work while the banner slider & content slider works fine. I have tried to disable the jQuery link from the content slider (which made the dropdown menu back to work), so I know they're conflicting.

Base on your source url provided above, you have something like this in your mark up:

```
<!-- jQuery #1 --><script src="http://www.helpmyedu.com/wp-content/themes/parallelus-moxie/assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.helpmyedu.com/wp-content/themes/parallelus-moxie/assets/js/twitter-bootstrap-hover-dropdown.js"></script>
<script>
// very simple to use!
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.js-activated').dropdownHover().dropdown();
});
</script>

<!-- CSS Embedded Here.. -->

<!-- jQuery #2 --><script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.helpmyedu.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.10.2'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.helpmyedu.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.2.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.helpmyedu.com/wp-content/plugins/alligator-popup/js/popup.js?ver=1.0.0'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.helpmyedu.com/wp-content/plugins/iphorm-form-builder/js/iphorm.js?ver=1.4.4'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.helpmyedu.com/wp-includes/js/swfupload/swfupload.js?ver=2201-20110113'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.helpmyedu.com/wp-includes/js/swfobject.js?ver=2.2-20120417'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.helpmyedu.com/wp-includes/js/swfupload/plugins/swfupload.swfobject.js?ver=2201a'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.helpmyedu.com/wp-includes/js/swfupload/plugins/swfupload.queue.js?ver=2201'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.helpmyedu.com/wp-content/plugins/revslider/rs-plugin/js/jquery.themepunch.plugins.min.js?ver=3.7.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.helpmyedu.com/wp-content/plugins/revslider/rs-plugin/js/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js?ver=3.7.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.helpmyedu.com/wp-content/themes/parallelus-moxie/assets/js/modernizr-2.6.2-respond-1.1.0.min.js?ver=2.6.2'></script>
```

I think you must remove the **jQuery#1** and move the other 2 scripts together with the others below like this:

```
<!-- CSS Embedded Here.. -->

<!-- jQuery #2 --><script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.helpmyedu.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.10.2'></script>
<script src="http://www.helpmyedu.com/wp-content/themes/parallelus-moxie/assets/js/twitter-bootstrap-hover-dropdown.js"></script>
<script>
// very simple to use!
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.js-activated').dropdownHover().dropdown();
});
</script>

<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.helpmyedu.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.2.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.helpmyedu.com/wp-content/plugins/alligator-popup/js/popup.js?ver=1.0.0'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.helpmyedu.com/wp-content/plugins/iphorm-form-builder/js/iphorm.js?ver=1.4.4'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.helpmyedu.com/wp-includes/js/swfupload/swfupload.js?ver=2201-20110113'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.helpmyedu.com/wp-includes/js/swfobject.js?ver=2.2-20120417'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.helpmyedu.com/wp-includes/js/swfupload/plugins/swfupload.swfobject.js?ver=2201a'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.helpmyedu.com/wp-includes/js/swfupload/plugins/swfupload.queue.js?ver=2201'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.helpmyedu.com/wp-content/plugins/revslider/rs-plugin/js/jquery.themepunch.plugins.min.js?ver=3.7.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.helpmyedu.com/wp-content/plugins/revslider/rs-plugin/js/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js?ver=3.7.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.helpmyedu.com/wp-content/themes/parallelus-moxie/assets/js/modernizr-2.6.2-respond-1.1.0.min.js?ver=2.6.2'></script>
```

Comment: I tried removing this line:
<script src="http://www.helpmyedu.com/wp-content/themes/parallelus-moxie/assets/js/jquery.js"></script>

still, the top dropdown menu doesn't work...

Comment: Even I copied the same line and replace the other, it still doesn't work *_* am I missing something?

Comment: Thanks, I think I get what you mean. However the initial two lines of jQuery that I mentioned top, is located on line33 & line327, but you have jsut pointed out another duplicated jQuery file at line76.... I'm not quite sure how to remove the line at line76 (since I don't see it in the header.php)... any suggestions?

Comment: Try to find the name of the document in your code [in the website application] using find all if you have that option in your ide to figure out the exact location where it embeds.

Answer (score 0):

See Console Error

[image]

Remove this code and your drop-down will work fine.

---

Are you including [Plugin file of twitter-bootstrap-hover-dropdown](https://github.com/CWSpear/twitter-bootstrap-hover-dropdown)

---

If you want to show menu on `hover`

see [Fiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/AndreasPizsa/NzvKC/)

Comment: removing .dropdownHover() doesn't fix the problem... also, yes I have included the twitter-bootstrap-hover-dropdown.js, but still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your resources are not loading properly on the initial page load that is why your drop downs are not working. I have not made a Wordpress theme in a while. But if you are making a theme to use within wordpress mostly all of your content for the theme should primarily be located in 'content/themes/"the name of your theme"'.

You have a folder called asdtest that has an index file that is testing for an initialization the drop-down hover then you are calling dropdown() remove that like so.

```
$('.js-activated').dropdownHover();
```

The docs says you can use either javascript or data-attributes to make it work so pick one method and now you are trying both.

I am trying to pin point it but i think your problems are in the structure of the wordpress theme folder and how that index page is being use initially. Trying to look around and see what is stopping your resources from loading and i think you may be good.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, Rick. I'm pretty sure all of the customization are edited within the theme folder. There is no "asdtest" folder, for testing purposes, it's only a "page" which I duplicated from my current homepage... I know the problem is between line33 & line327 of [this page](http://helpmyedu.com/asdtest-2), but I just don't know how to fix it!